# Mono не компилирует код написанный в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono

Mono C# compiler version 5.12.0.226 не компилирует код написанный в Visual Studio 2017. Задача сдается сегодня последний день и у меня подгорает от того, что есть работающий код (в VS компилируется), а сдать его не могу по неведомым причинам. 
Подскажите как решается проблема, хотя бы с чего мне начать ее решать.
Ниже лог ошибок и код.
Лог:

```
 compile error: /usercode/file.cs(32,58): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
 /usercode/file.cs(35,64): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `/', expecting `,', `;', or `='
 /usercode/file.cs(52,16): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(52,25): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(52,32): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(52,48): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(52,52): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `++' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(53,14): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
 /usercode/file.cs(59,16): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(59,25): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(59,32): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(59,48): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(59,52): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `++' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(60,14): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
 /usercode/file.cs(60,14): error CS8041: Primary constructor already has a body
 /usercode/file.cs(73,15): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(73,32): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `==' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(73,58): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Данные не содержат информации в формате: ID погрузчика/ID контейнера: время погрузки этого контейнера на этом погрузчике в минутах.'
 /usercode/file.cs(73,47): error CS0106: The modifier `new' is not valid for this item
 /usercode/file.cs(73,47): error CS1520: Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type
 /usercode/file.cs(74,19): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(74,27): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 /usercode/file.cs(194,67): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
 /usercode/file.cs(324,17): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `void', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', or `struct'
 cat: /usercode/errors.txt: No such file or directory
```

Код:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 namespace TheBestDistributionOfContainers
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = Console.ReadLine(); // Ждем данные в стандартном потоке
        var parseData = ParseinitialData(data); // Конвертируем данные в объекты

        var controllerDistributionContainers = new ControllerDistributionContainers(parseData); // Создаем контроллер отвечающий за респределние контейнеров
        controllerDistributionContainers.SetBestAllocationContainersOnTrucks(); // Распределяем контейнеры наилучшим образом

        var result = controllerDistributionContainers.GetDistributionContainersString(); // конвертируем ответ в строку
        Console.Write(result);
    }


    // Распрсиваем строку с данными о скорости разгурзки определенных контейнеров определенными разгрузчиками
    private static List<LoaderContainerTime> ParseinitialData(string data)
    {
        // Распарсиваем строку с определенным контейнером и его разгрузчиком
        LoaderContainerTime parseinitialDataContainer(string dataContainer)
        {
            // пример что на входе: ID погрузчика/ID контейнера: время погрузки этого контейнера на этом погрузчике в минутах: 8/6:16 
            string idLoader = Regex.Split(dataContainer, "/")[0];
            string idContainer = Regex.Split(Regex.Split(dataContainer, "/")[1], ":")[0];
            string time = Regex.Split(Regex.Split(dataContainer, "/")[1], ":")[1];

            var loaderContainerTime = new LoaderContainerTime();
            loaderContainerTime.Time = Int32.Parse(time);
            loaderContainerTime.IdLoader = Int32.Parse(idLoader);
            loaderContainerTime.IdContainer = Int32.Parse(idContainer);
            return loaderContainerTime;
        }

        var result = new List<LoaderContainerTime>();


        var arrData = Regex.Split(data, "\n");

        // Очищаем строку от лишних символов
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.Length; i++)
        {
            arrData[i] = arrData[i].Replace("п»ї", "");
            arrData[i] = arrData[i].Replace("\r", "");
        }

        // парсим строчки
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                result.Add(parseinitialDataContainer(arrData[i]));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Входные данные не могут быть обработаны т.к. не соотвествуют шаблону.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (result.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Данные не содержат информации в формате: ID погрузчика/ID контейнера: время погрузки этого контейнера на этом погрузчике в минутах.");
        return result;
    }

}


public class ControllerDistributionContainers
{
    private List<LoaderContainerTime> LoaderContainerTimes { get; set; }
    private List<Loader> Loaders { get; set; }
    private List<Container> Containers { get; set; }


    public ControllerDistributionContainers(List<LoaderContainerTime> loaderContainerTimes)
    {
        this.LoaderContainerTimes = loaderContainerTimes;

        Initialization();
    }

    /// <summary> Инициализация, высенесена отдельно т.к. объект нужно переинициализировать в другом методе </summary>
    private void Initialization()
    {
        Loaders = new List<Loader>();
        Containers = new List<Container>();

        // Считаем сколько загрузчиков и грузов с какими Id у нас вообще есть, столько их и создаем
        foreach (var i in LoaderContainerTimes)
        {
            if (SearchLoader(i.IdLoader) == null)
            {
                Loaders.Add(new Loader() { Id = i.IdLoader });
            }

            if (SearchContainer(i.IdContainer) == null)
            {
                Containers.Add(new Container() { Id = i.IdContainer });
            }

            // Закидываем контейнеру информацию о скорости разгрузки определенным погрзчиком
            SearchContainer(i.IdContainer).LoadersTimesAdd(i);
        }
    }

    private Loader SearchLoader(int id)
    {
        foreach (var i in Loaders)
        {
            if (i.Id == id) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Container SearchContainer(int id)
    {
        foreach (var i in Containers)
        {
            if (i.Id == id) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary> Вернуть суммарное время работы при текущем распределении контейнеров</summary>
    public int GetTimeWork()
    {
        return GetTheMostLoadedLoader().TotalWorkingTime;
    }

    /// <summary> Венрунть в виде строки распределение грузов. в виде строк, разделённых символом перевода 
    /// строки ('\n') в формате: ID погрузчика:ID контейнера;ID контейнера;...ID контейнера; </summary>
    public string GetDistributionContainersString()
    {
        string result = "";

        foreach (var i in Loaders)
        {
            result += i.Id + ":";

            foreach (var c in i.Containers)
            {
                result += c.Id + ";";
            }

            result += "\n";
        }


        return result;
    }

    /// <summary> Распределить контейнеры наилучшим образом</summary>
    public void SetBestAllocationContainersOnTrucks()
    {
        // Если выполнять как задачу комбинаторики, то вариантов решения n погрузчиков в степени n грузов, вариант не подходит.

        // Переинициализируем контроллер чтобы удалить старое распределение грузов
        Initialization();

        // 1 ступень. В массив прогрузчиков распределяем контейнеры по эффективности разгрузки. Контейнер достается тому кто разгрузит за лучшее время
        // УЖЕ НА ЭТОМ ЭТАПЕ ДОСТИГАЕТСЯ МАСКСИМАЛЬНАЯ СКОРОСТЬ НА ТЕСТОВЫХ ВХОДНЫХ ДАННЫХ ИЗ 10 КОНТЕЙНЕРОВ.
        foreach (var i in Containers)
        {
            SearchLoader(i.GetTopLoaderContainerTime()[0].IdLoader).ContainersAdd(i);
        }

        // 2 ступень.
        // Проверяем возможно ли перераспределить с самого занятого погрузчика контейнеры другим погрузчикам для уменьшения времени разгрузки чтобы
        // исключить ситуацию, когда самому навороченному погрузчику достались все грузы т.к. он эффективней всех их разгружает.
        // Вводим коэффициент эффективности (КПД) перераспределения. Эффективно то перераспределение, что будет иметь минимальную разницу во времени
        // между текущим разгрузчиком, которого освобождаем и следующим. n = V0 / V1;
        // Таким образом мы максимально эффективно перераспределим контейнеры с самых занятых погрузчиков
        while (redistributedContainersForEfficientRedistribution()) { }; // Запускаем рекурсию, пока получается улучшить время этим занимаемся

        // 3 ступень.
        // Проверяем нельзя ли перераспределить с других погрузчиков грузы так чтобы освободить какой-нибудь прогрузчик и накинуть ему еще 1 контейнер 
        // с самого занятого для уменьшения  времени. Требует много вычислений
        while (tryToRedistributeContainersFromTheBusyLoader()) { }; // Запускаем рекурсию, пока получается улучшить время этим занимаемся

        // НИЖЕ ДЕТАЛИ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ АЛГОРИТМОВ ОПИСАННЫХ ВЫШЕ _______________________________________________________________
        // объяснение дано в месте где вызывается ф-я
        bool redistributedContainersForEfficientRedistribution()
        {
            // Выводим список грузов по эффективности их перераспределения, где под индексом 0 находится лучший контейнер к перераспределению
            var mostLoadedLoader = GetTheMostLoadedLoader();
            var listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution = new List<ContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution>();
            foreach (var i in mostLoadedLoader.Containers) // формируем список
            {
                var forAddWithList = new ContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution();
                forAddWithList.Container = i;
                forAddWithList.IdNowLoader = mostLoadedLoader.Id;

                var speedNowLoader = i.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(mostLoadedLoader.Id); // Скорость текущего разгрузчика
                var nextLoader = i.GetNextLoaderInTOPContainerTime(mostLoadedLoader.Id);
                if (nextLoader == null) break; // Значит перебрали уже всех
                var idNextLoader = nextLoader.IdLoader;    // Id следущего разгрузчика по скорости разгрузки 
                forAddWithList.IdNextLoader = idNextLoader;
                var speedNextLoader = i.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(idNextLoader); // Скорость следущего разгрузчика
                forAddWithList.Efficiency = decimal.Parse(speedNowLoader.ToString()) / decimal.Parse(speedNextLoader.ToString()); // Эффективность  n = V0 / V1;

                listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution.Add(forAddWithList);
            }
            // Сортируем в порядке убывания эффективности перераспределения
            listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution = listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution.OrderByDescending(u => u.Efficiency).ToList();

            // Пробуем перераспределить контейнеры с самго занятого разгрузчика до тех пор, пока это будет уменьшать суммарное время разгрузки
            for (var i = 0; i < listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution.Count; i++)
            {
                var redistribution = listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution[i]; // перераспределение с которым работаем, сделано т.к. иначе слишком длинные имена
                if (redistribution.IsRedistributed) // если данное перераспределение еще не исполнялось
                {    
                    var timeNow = GetTimeWork();// Считаем текущее время разгрузки
                    ToTransferContainer(redistribution.Container.Id, redistribution.IdNowLoader, redistribution.IdNextLoader); // передаем контейнер
                    var newTime = GetTimeWork();// Считаем изменилось ли время
                    if (newTime < timeNow) // Время улучшилось, тогда так и оставляем
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else  // Время ухудшилось, значит нельзя перераспределить, следующему по эффективности разгрузчику. Соотвественно проверяем коэф.эффектиности
                          // с другими разгрузчиками до тех пор пока этот коэф. не станет меньше коэффициента перераспределения худшего из грузов
                    {
                        ToTransferContainer(redistribution.Container.Id, redistribution.IdNextLoader, redistribution.IdNowLoader); // возвращаем контейнер на место
                        // находим самый худший показатель эффективности перераспределния других грузов
                        var worstPerformanceMeasure = 1.0m;
                        foreach (var ii in listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution)
                        {
                            if (ii.Efficiency < worstPerformanceMeasure) worstPerformanceMeasure = ii.Efficiency;
                        }
                        // перебираем всех погрузчиков, кроме двух и считаем какова эффективности перераспределения им
                        var alternativeRedistribution = new ContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution
                        {
                            Efficiency = -1.0m,
                            Container = redistribution.Container,
                            IdNowLoader = redistribution.IdNowLoader,
                            IsRedistributed = false
                        };
                        foreach (var ii in Loaders)
                        {
                            if (ii.Id == mostLoadedLoader.Id || ii.Id == redistribution.IdNextLoader) continue; // пропускам тех, что уже исследовали

                            var speedNowLoader = redistribution.Container.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(mostLoadedLoader.Id); // Скорость текущего разгрузчика
                            var speedNextLoader = redistribution.Container.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(ii.Id); // Скорость следущего разгрузчика
                            var efficiency = speedNowLoader / speedNextLoader; // Эффективность  n = V0 / V1;

                            if(efficiency > alternativeRedistribution.Efficiency)
                            {
                                alternativeRedistribution.Efficiency = efficiency;
                                alternativeRedistribution.IdNextLoader = ii.Id;
                            }
                        }
                        // если удалось найти перераспределение этого контейнера за эффективность не ниже самого худшего  на данный момент, то запихиваем
                        // в лист перераспределения
                        if(alternativeRedistribution.Efficiency != -1.0m && alternativeRedistribution.Efficiency > worstPerformanceMeasure)
                        {
                            listOfContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution.Add(alternativeRedistribution);
                        }
                        redistribution.IsRedistributed = true; // указываем, что старое указание на перераспределение выполнено
                    }

                }
            }

            return false; // Так и не удалось улучшить время за эту итерацию рекурсии, значит выходим из нее
        }

        // объяснение дано в месте где вызывается ф-я
        bool tryToRedistributeContainersFromTheBusyLoader()
        {
            var mostLoadedLoader = GetTheMostLoadedLoader();
            for (var i = 0; i < mostLoadedLoader.Containers.Count; i++) // пробуем перекинуть любой из контейнеров c самого занятого
            {
                for (var ii = 0; ii < Loaders.Count; ii++) // любому погрузчику
                {
                    for (var iii = 0; iii < Loaders[ii].Containers.Count; iii++)  // вместо любого груза этого прогрузчика
                    {
                        for (var iiii = 0; iiii < Loaders.Count; iiii++) // который отдастся любому из погрузчиков
                        {
                            var timeNow = GetTimeWork();    // засекаем текущее время разгрузки
                            // перемещаем контейнер спперва из более свободного любому погрузчику
                            var containerOne = Loaders[ii].Containers[iii].Id;
                            var containerTwo = mostLoadedLoader.Containers[i].Id;
                            ToTransferContainer(containerOne, Loaders[ii].Id, Loaders[iiii].Id);
                            // теперь перемещаем контейнер из самого занятого более свободному погрузчику
                            ToTransferContainer(containerTwo, mostLoadedLoader.Id, Loaders[ii].Id);
                            // засекаем время.
                            var newTime = GetTimeWork();    // засекаем текущее время разгрузки

                            if (newTime < timeNow) // время улучшили, возвращаем true
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else // не получилось улучшить время возвращаем контенеры на место
                            {

                                ToTransferContainer(containerTwo, Loaders[ii].Id, mostLoadedLoader.Id);
                                ToTransferContainer(containerOne, Loaders[iiii].Id, Loaders[ii].Id);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }


    }


    /// <summary> Перемещае контейнер </summary>
    private void ToTransferContainer(int idContainer, int idGivingLoader, int idReceivingLoader)
    {
        var transferContainer = SearchContainer(idContainer);               // находим перемещаемый контейнер
        SearchLoader(idReceivingLoader).ContainersAdd(transferContainer);   // Записываем контейнер новому погрузчику
        SearchLoader(idGivingLoader).ContainersRemove(transferContainer);  // Удаляем его из списка у старого погрузчика
    }

    /// <summary> Локальная структура - груз и эффективность его перераспределения </summary>
    struct ContainersOnTheEffectivenessOfTheirRedistribution
    {
        public Container Container;
        public decimal Efficiency;
        public int IdNowLoader;
        public int IdNextLoader;
        public bool IsRedistributed; // выполнено ли перераспределение
    }

    /// <summary> Вернуть самого занятого загрузчика</summary>
    private Loader GetTheMostLoadedLoader()
    {
        var maxTime = 0;
        Loader mostLoadedLoader = null;
        foreach (var i in Loaders)
        {
            if(i.TotalWorkingTime > maxTime)
            {
                maxTime = i.TotalWorkingTime;
                mostLoadedLoader = i;
            }
        }

        return mostLoadedLoader;
    }
}

/// <summary> Загрузчик </summary>
public class Loader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Container> Containers { get; private set; } = new List<Container>();

    public int TotalWorkingTime { get; private set; } = 0;

    public void ContainersAdd(Container container)
    {
        Containers.Add(container);

        TotalWorkingTime += container.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(this.Id);
    }

    public void ContainersRemove(Container container)
    {
        Containers.Remove(container);

        TotalWorkingTime -= container.GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(this.Id);
    }
}

/// <summary> Контейнер из задачи</summary>
public class Container
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary> Время разгрузки на разных разгрузчиках</summary>
    private List<LoaderContainerTime> LoadersTimes { get; set; } = new List<LoaderContainerTime>();

    public void LoadersTimesAdd(LoaderContainerTime loaderContainerTime)
    {
        LoadersTimes.Add(loaderContainerTime);
    }

    /// <summary> Вернуть время разгрузки этого контейнера данным рзагрузчиком</summary>
    public int GetTimeSpeedWithLoader(int IdLoader)
    {
        foreach (var i in LoadersTimes)
        {
            if (i.IdLoader == IdLoader) return i.Time;
        }

        throw new Exception("Такого разгрузчика не зафиксированно");
    }

    /// <summary> Вернуть ТОП в порядке возрастания времени разгрузки этого контейнера разгрузчиками.
    ///  0 месте лучший погрузчик</summary>
    public LoaderContainerTime[] GetTopLoaderContainerTime()
    {
        if (LoadersTimes.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Не известно ни чего о погрузчиках работающих с этим контейнером");
        var sortedLoadersTimes = LoadersTimes.OrderBy(u => u.Time);
        return sortedLoadersTimes.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary> Вернуть следущего по эффективности разгрузчика данного контейнера после Id указанного или null</summary>
    public LoaderContainerTime GetNextLoaderInTOPContainerTime(int IdLoader)
    {
        var top = GetTopLoaderContainerTime();

        for(var i = 0; 0 < top.Length; i++)
        {
            if (top[i].IdLoader == IdLoader)
                try
                {
                    return top[i + 1];
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }

        }

        return null;
    }

}

/// <summary> Строка поступающая на вход программе, содержащая id контейнера, разгрузчика и время разгрузки</summary>
public class LoaderContainerTime
{
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int IdLoader { get; set; }
    public int IdContainer { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: по списку ошибок похоже на потерянную или лишнюю фигурную скобку. Компилируете под Mono из консоли или через IDE?

Comment: @rdorn отправляю на сервер где принимают задачу. Копирую и вставляю через ctrl+a ctrl+c, поэтому вряд ли что-то теряется, последние и первые скобки на местах

Comment: Внутри метода `ParseinitialData` определена локальная функция `parseinitialDataContainer` - это фича появилась лишь недавно в C#7. Такой возможности нет в Mono. Сделайте эту локальную функцию методом класса.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сейчас попробуем, спасибо, у меня там таких вещей много сейчас поменяю

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov на секунду опередили, хотя я специально посмотрел, в последней версии вроде добавили

Comment: @rdorn - ясно, будем знать. Автор, какую версию Mono используете? Может стоит обновиться до последней?

Comment: @rdorn там на сервере 12 версия а не последняя, последняя вроде 14

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich ну тогда аккуратнее с конструкциями из C# 7+, все или некоторые могут не поддерживаться

Comment: [тут](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/) пишут что поддерживается, причем давно, прошлогодний релиз... может что-то поломали или не допилили...

Comment: Еще, как вариант, на сервере в параметрах компиляции указана версия языка ниже 7

Comment: Заработало, спасибо, можете в ответ написать, я галочку поставлю :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 для компиляции использует C# 7.x по умолчанию.

В вашем коде используются конструкции из C# 7.x, в частности локальные функции.

Согласно описанию релиза [Mono 5.10](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.10.0/), начиная с этой версии Mono C# compiler (mcs) также поддерживает конструкции C# 7.x. В версии [Mono 5.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/) эту версию языка в Mono поддерживал только Roslyn (csc).

У вас используется более старшая версия, следовательно проблема может быть связана с параметрами компиляции. Компилятору можно явно указать какую версию языка использовать и в вашем случае она явно ниже 7.

Так как компиляция у вас происходит на сервере и вы не имеете доступа к параметрам компиляции, то решение может быть только одно - отказаться от использования конструкций C# 7.x и ограничиться, например, версией 5.0. Если более конкретно - переписать локальные функции в виде приватных методов класса, а также при необходимости заменить и другие конструкции на эквивалентные.

Чтобы облегчить задачу поиска несовместимых конструкций или просто избежать случайного использования, в настройках проекта студии можно явно указать допустимую версию языка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]